# Extract entire row from a list

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm more from the SQL world, but I have received one excel file with names, emails, postal codes, phone numbers and so on. I need to filter/extract all the row information from some individuals. I have the complete list (as an example)

```
1   John        Doe         john@example.com    28032
2   Ken         Smith       ken@example.com     28012
3   Abraham     Johnson     abraham@example.com 28001
4   Don         Williams    don@example.com     28022
5   Brenda      Jones       brenda@example.com  28031
6   Kenneth     Brown       brown@example.com   28045
7   Jennifer    Davis       davis@example.com   28005
8   Brittany    Miller      miller@example.com  28021
9   Martin      Wilson      wilson@example.com  28032
10  Roger       Moore       john@example.com    28004
```

And the list of people I need to extract:

```
Ken     Smith
Martin  Wilson
Brenda  Jones
```

The result expected is the following:

```
2   Ken     Smith   ken@example.com     28012
5   Brenda  Jones   brenda@example.com  28031
9   Martin  Wilson  wilson@example.com  28032
```

As I said, I have some SQL background, and I would do with a simple `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name='John Doe'` or similar, but I am totally lost with Excel. I don't know if I can do this with a formula a VBA macro or is simpler than I think.

PS: I don't mind if solution proposed works with MS Excel or LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

[image]

We placed the lookup names in columns **G** and **H**.
  In **F1** we enter the array formula:

```
=MATCH(G1 & H1,A:A & B:B,0)
```

and copy down.  Then in **I1** enter:

```
=INDEX(C:C,$F1)
```

and copy both across and down.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: It worked. But, what are neccesary here Array formulas?

Comment: @fernandezr On my system *(Windows 10 / Excel365)* array formulation is necessary.